# Accessing an embedded list through iteration

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I want to make a folder "A" in folder "UK" and then in that folder make several other folders and then go back to folder "UK" and make folder "B" and in that folder create several more folders and repeat this process x times based on lists with folder names.

Currently, the code will create all the sector list folders in each sector folder (around 119 folders total) But I want only the specified folders for each nested list around 5-10 per sector.

for example, I create a folder called Commercial Services in that folder should be 'Advertising Marketing Services', 'Commercial Printing Forms', 'Financial Publishing Services', 'Miscellaneous Commercial Services', 'Personnel Services'. However, I get all of the folders in "sectorsList"

```
sectorsList = [CommercialServices, Miscellaneous, ConsumerNonDurables, ..., Minerals]
sectors =  ['Commercial Services', 'Miscellaneous', 'Consumer NonDurables',..., Minerals']
```

I want to have a file \UK\Commercial Services\Advertising Marketing Services
                                             \Commercial Printing Forms
                                             \etc
    and then \UK\Miscellaneous\Investment Trusts etc

```
for i in sectors:
    p = Path("D:\\Data\\UK\\"+str(i))
    p.mkdir()
    for ind in sectorsList:
        print(ind)
        for sec in ind:
            p = Path("D:\\Data\\UK\\"+str(i)+"\\"+str(sec))
            p.mkdir()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar problem I managed to solve it using .pop(). The issue with the first script was that the embedded lists seemed to add all the embedded lists to each "ind" so instead of around 5 sub-sectors in each "Ind" it had 119. Using .pop and then iterating through its output f overcame this and then I think there may have been a logic issue as well in that the script wouldn't know to go back to the original directory after each pass.

```
def getSector(ind):
    index = sectorsListString.index(ind)
    f = sectorsList[index]
    return f



for n in sectorsClean:
    f = getSector(n)
    p = Path("D:\\Data\\UK\\"+str(n))
    p.mkdir()
    for i in f:
        p = Path("D:\\Data\\UK\\"+str(n)+"\\"+str(i))
        p.mkdir()
```